# Why is this json script not working in IE7 & 8, but works in all other browsers?

Tags: jquery, json

I am almost done with my sites rebuild and am now in the testing phase. While testing in IE7 and 8 i found out that becuase of  a json script I have my jquery scripts will not work properly, even though they do in all other browsers, including IE9.

The page is: http://www.carcityofdanbury.com/New/?cat=01&do=View&stock=18481

The script is the Info Request form, something in this line: 
`".append("<p>Thank you " + data.name + ",</p><p class=\"indent\">we recieved your info request " + data.for + " on our<br />'.$vehicle.' and will contact you shortly.</p>")"` is causing the jquery tabs to no longer work.

I did the php and jquery coding, but hired someone to do the json, so I do not know how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Hired someone to do the JSON?

Comment: the "Info Request" form was done by someone else

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `data.for` and it sounds a bit like you (the person who wrote the code) are trying to access one of the reserved names. Even though `data.for` should be valid, IE doesn't like names which it thinks are special (class for example). `data.class` would cause a problem in IE, even though it's valid.

Try to rename `data.for` to something else `data._for` for example. Make sure you update the `01/Resources/infoRequest.php` PHP file to return the *new* value as well.

Comment: I changed data.for to data.test and that did not solve the issue.

Comment: You need to update `01/Resources/infoRequest.php` as well. The data being returned from the AJAX call is still referencing `for`, so it now says `...we recieved your info request undefined on our...`. I don't see the original error any more in IE though.

Comment: This is so wierd because that solved the IE8 issue, but still not IE7.

Comment: Alternatively, try accessing `data['for']` instead of `data.for`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it... There was an extra comma in the code:

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        // Tabs
            $("#tabs").tabs();

        // Google map
            $(\'#embed\').gmap3(
                {action: \'addMarker\', lat:41.40372, lng:-73.45844, map:{center: true, zoom: 17, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}}
            );

        // Pic popup
            $("#viewPics").fancybox({
                \'type\': \'iframe\', \'transitionIn\': \'fade\', \'transitionOut\': \'fade\', \'width\': 900, \'height\': 500, \'autoScale\': false, \'scrolling\': \'no\'
            });

        // Form Validation
            jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
            $("#infoForm").validate({

                invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
                    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    if (errors) {
                        var message = errors == 1
                            ? \'You missed 1 required field.\'
                            : \'You missed \' + errors + \' required fields\';
                        $("li.Error span").html(message);
                        $("li.Error").show();
                    } else {
                        $("li.Error").hide();
                    }
                },

                onkeyup: false,
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "01/Resources/infoRequest.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        cache:false,
                        data: $("#infoForm").serialize(),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("li.Error").hide();
                            $("#contact_form").html(\'<div id="message"></div>\');
                            $("#message").html("<h2>Info Request Submitted!</h2>")
                            .append("<p>Thank you " + data.name + ",</p><p class=\"indent\">we recieved your info request " + data.test + " on our<br />'.$vehicle.' and will contact you shortly.</p>")
                            .hide()
                            .fadeIn(2500, function() {
                                $("#message").append("<p>Would you like to <a href=\"?cat=02&stock='.$stock.'\">prefill an application</a> now?</p>")
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }, <------- This guy was the culprit

            });

        });
    </script>
```